# How to Format a date pass as a parameter to a function and return data is a string with "yyyy/mm/dd" format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Format a date pass as a parameter to a function and return data is a string with "yyyy/mm/dd" format ?
for example if I would want to format a string retrieved from textbox and I want a special function to format it and return as a string format.

```
string myDate = txtJoiningDate.Text,
```

my function should be :

```
 public string GetFormattedDate(string myDate)
 {
   //Formating should happen here.
   return myDate;
 }
```

Comment: What is the format of `myDate` ??? You need to first parse the string `myDate` to `DateTime` object and then you can return formatted date using format `yyyy/MM/dd`.

Comment: @Habib : Thanks. WORKED FOR ME. after it worked , I have posted my code here.

Comment: You have changed your parameter type to `object` from `string`, The code you have posted is not the proper way of doing it, It would have been better if you have used `DateTime.TryParse` for parsing your string date and then later returning the formatted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public string GetFormattedDate(String MyDateTime)
    {
        //Formating should happen here.
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(MyDateTime);
        return dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");            
    }
```

also can be done with this

```
 string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks sudhakar. but one problem in  return MyDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); is, if again I want that data to be in date format  means it's changing and not satisfying my requirement.My requirement is it must be "yyyy/mm/dd". the above post works fine according to all situation.

Comment: @tnw : Could you please check it now.

Comment: @Sudhakar : No , again if i use the formatted date now which is string,  storing it in a date variable and do some datetime implementation, the format completely changes. Can't able to display that format (from user other format is unacceptable).

Comment: @tnw Please, instead of spending all that time telling other people how bad their code is, show us how its done properly.  I don't see a single answer from you in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Hurrey.I got the answer.Working 100%. Hope will be helpful for others.

```
 public string FormatPostingDate(object obj)
 {
     if (obj != null && obj.ToString() != string.Empty)
     {
         DateTime postingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj);
         return string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", postingDate);
     }
     return string.Empty;
 }
```

also can be done with this

```
 using System.Globalization;

 string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Worst community wiki ever. Quite frankly, this solution sucks. Formatting a date from a string is exceedingly simple these days and this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Why pass in an object when you *clearly* only want to accept a string? Why not use TryParse? Why should this even be its own function AT ALL? This can be done in one or two lines.

Comment: @tnw : yes it can be. but as it is required in allover application that is the reason I need it to be in a single function, such that I need not to reprat the line of code again and again.

Comment: @tnw : badly written code ? I didn't understand. i m telling you nearly 20 to 30 places i need date to be formatted in this manner. Please tell me in this situation will it be better to write 30 * 2 "on your point of view, This can be done in one or two lines." = 60 lines of code ? Can you pls show me few lines of your code which means best.

Comment: @tnw : i am waiting for a solution from you and can you pls help me for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692945/how-to-create-audio-video-related-c-sharp-asp-net-web-app post ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the string to a DateTime object however you need to make sure that the format you are going to parse will work.

take a look at DateTime.Parse (or TryParse):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

then you simply do:

```
// lets say you are creating your datetime:
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 11, 1);
return dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

the above will return 01/11/2013

more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: mine was an example - still no reason to downvote even though the links were given for reference in addition to explanation what the output would be from the sample provided. no excuse for downvoting abuse.... ;-)

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas : Even if your solution is not correct, but you are correct on the following manner.links are helpful. it's ridiculous to  downvote. no excuse for downvoting abuse....;-)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Look at the guy's profile.  He has more downvotes than upvotes.  That tells you he is more interested in downvoting for nonsense reasons than actually helping people. +1

Comment: You could probably make a better impression here if you used proper capitalization and punctuation in your answers.

Comment: @L_7337 : Thanks.We should stop these type of people.